# Is it possible to have a published script without putting the add-on in the Google Add-On store

Tags: google-apps-script, publish

I created a spreadsheet to help with character creation for a table top roleplaying game.  Currently, every time I'm saving the file as a different name and/or moving it to a different file in my google drive, the script tells me that the publisher is unknown and I have to go through the authorization process.

I'm interested in publishing the script to bypass this authorization process so that others can use the tool and freely make characters without having to repeatedly go through the authorization process, but the script isn't particularly useful outside the context of the spreadsheet I created so it's not something that should be downloaded independently.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary. From this [Add-on Authorization Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle):

> Specifically, the installed and enabled states determine which authorization mode the `onOpen(e)` function runs in. Apps Script passes the authorization mode as the `authMode` property of the [event parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events), `e`; the value of `e.authMode` corresponds to a constant in the [`ScriptApp.AuthMode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/auth-mode) enum.

Also, you can publish an Add-On to be [restricted to a specific domain](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide). If the Add-on is not being published publicly, then it does not go through the approval process.

You may check this post:
[Google Apps script publishing addon for internal use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990006/google-apps-script-publishing-addon-for-internal-use)