# How to fix the "Your account does not belong to the same domain as this cloud project or app" error?

Tags: configuration, sdk, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I'm updating an app on G Suite Marketplace SDK. It used to work by just changing the script version at the "App Configuration" Tab, and click Save.

Now it posted a warning at the top of the page saying:

> Your account does not belong to the same domain as this cloud project or app

and the `Save` button is grey and not clickable.

Error image can be seen here:

[image: marketplace SDK error screenshot]

What is the issue and where should I go to check and verify the domains?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terms:

- GCP - Google Cloud Platform
- Apps Script project - Your Apps Script file

---

Your Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project that is associated with your Apps Script project is in a default category of "No organization." That's the problem.

If you already have an organization set up in your GCP, then skip down to the "Migrate your Cloud Platform Project" section below.

If you have not created an organization in your Cloud Platform project, then you need to do that. After creating an organization, you must migrate the Cloud Platform project for your add-on in "No organization" to your Organization.

[Your organization is your "company."](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations)

Your Google Workspace account (formerly G Suite) can only have one Organization provisioned with it. You probably have Cloud Platform projects that were automatically put under the "No organization" category. If you already have an Organization in your Cloud Platform project, then you won't see an option to create another one.

[Create an organization in Cloud Platform Project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)

### Migrate your Cloud Platform Project:

- Open the [Cloud Platform Project](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?authuser=0) for your add-on
- Open [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?authuser=0)
- Click Settings
- Click the Migrate link

[image: Migrate Cloud Project]

- Choose the organization to migrate to
- Click the button:
- Wait for confirmation that the migration happened

[image: Migrate Button]

I migrated a Cloud Project for an add-on without any problem. You can also change ownership of a Cloud Project from one Google account to another Google account.

My assumption is, that the Cloud Project isn't affected by migrating it because it's basically running independently from whatever account or organization it's associated with.

The only way to know that for sure is if someone from Google provided an answer, but the only way to get support for Cloud Projects is to buy a support plan, and the least expensive one is $100 dollars a month per user.

[Google Cloud Project support plans](https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans)

Technically, Apps Script is not supported by Google, and there is no Google contact person to get answers from.

With the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK, you must associate an Apps Script project with the Cloud Platform project. If you changed ownership of the Apps Script file that the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK was associated with, then there would likely be a problem.

You'd need to make sure that whoever owned the Cloud Platform Project also owned the Apps Script file. If the Apps Script file was deleted, then that would kill the add-on.

Comment: Thanks Alan for your answer, I'm having the same problem! Just an additional question: are we sure that there will be no impact on the existing G Suite Marketplace listing when we migrate it to our Organization? (whether it's an add-on, a web app, a chatbot, ...) Thanks!

Comment: See updated answer at end.  I know about add-ons, but not other types of apps associated with the Cloud Project.

Comment: I just started getting the same error when trying to release an update for my Docs Add-on, this took care of it

Comment: TL;DR migrate your addon project to your organisation (first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue and I share what I did that is a bit different of previous answer.

I have a Gmail account that manage the Apps Script and also have a workspace domain. When the first time I publish the app I move the GCP project created in my Gmail acocunt to the GCP Oragnization of my domain. Previously it never generate problem but today I have the eror message

> Your account does not belong to the same domain as this cloud project or app

What I did :
On the workspace domain with the super admin account that have the GCP Organizaional Owner role I added my Gmail account as Oragnization manager

Organization Role Administrator

=> It does not work.

So I finally added my domain account as owner of project and it works.

It seems something change in the Marketplace Workspace SDK management and if a project belong to an organization, now you can no longer modify Marketplace item with a Gmail account.