# Migrating from Chrome store to g suite marketplace

Tags: gsuite-addons

My app got bumped from the Chrome store and it looks like it needs to be moved to the g suite marketplace.  I started the configuration process and right away at the top it says "your account does not belong to the same domain as this cloud project or app".  This application was written under my incubator company then a new company was spun up and the app was moved over.  But the operations and startup of the application for many years was under the original domain.  I can't migrate the google side of the application/oauth/etc over without seriously impacting my business customers.  But I own both domains.  I can't seem to proceed and I'm thinking this may be why.  What can I do?  I need to get this app installed at several new customer's locations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update apps on google marketplace - Your account does not belong to the same domain as this cloud project or app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719250/cannot-update-apps-on-google-marketplace-your-account-does-not-belong-to-the-s)

Comment: You should contact the G Suite support for this particular case, here is the link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en