# Unable to Configure Standard Google Cloud Platform project for App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to configure an existing standard Google Cloud Platform project for my App Script.

Path: Resources --> Cloud Platform project.

I am the owner of the GCP project. When I try to add the project number I get the below error message.

'you cannot switch to a Cloud Platform project outside of the script owner's Cloud Organisation.'

[image]

Could you please help with it why I am getting this error?

Comment: Are you currently logged into more than one account?

Comment: Also, is your Cloud Project in the "No Organization" category?  In the past, Cloud Projects would often get automatically assigned to the "No Organization" category.  Now, you must have a named Organization and put the Cloud Project into that organization.  I'm not sure, but this issue may be similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/62719250/2946873](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62719250/2946873)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Cooper and Alan.

My email Id domain which I logged into the sheet/app script and the GCP project gsuite domain(organization) is different but my email id has owner permissions on the GCP project.

Example: Just these are example domains for understanding purpose.

 My email id:  mahesh@test.com
 GCP project gsuite domain : example.com(organization)

Comment: Are you the G Suite Admin?

Comment: Yes, I am the Gsuite admin of the GCP organization having a different email id (mahesh106@example.com) but I am trying to publish the add-on with a different account (mahesh@test.com) and this account has editor permissions on the project.

Comment: You may need owner permissions, and not just editor. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#using_basic_roles.  Did you try as owner?